# Cmd Line Utility: CPU Mem and Timestamp

Tags: shell, command-line

I wonder if there's any utility that gives me only the cpu usage, memory usage and a timestamp of a specified process?  I want to continuously monitor some process.  It should keep running like `top`, but with a timestamp and without all the other info except cpu and memory usages.  Thanks.

Comment: have you checked the manpage for the top command? It can do quite a lot of things, e.g. limit to one process or select the columns displayed - what is it you're missing?

Comment: It can select the columns? I didn't find that option.  Also, I want a timestamp for each record, I cannot find such an option either.

Comment: the manpage for my debian's top is 1000 lines long - you can press f or F while it's running to be able to edit the fields, you can save the configuration - it's worth studying the manpage for this  - except if you are talking about some embedded and maybe busybox-based top I'm afraid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple tool `timestamp.pl` to print the timestamp, which can be used to record the timestamp of the ouput of `top`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) { print localtime() . ": $_"; }
```

Achieve this by a simple pipeline command: `top -b -d 5 | ./timestamp.pl`